# Clear fields in Live Search?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am using php+html (with Ajax) files where I display contents of MySQL in a webpage. The `index.php` is where I display the contents while it extracts the contents from `fetch.php`. I have followed a tutorial from this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCsPAquMNVw

What I am facing a problem is, that when I type something in search, a value is displayed if it contains in the sql table and if the value is not contained in sql table, a `"Data not found";` will be called. However, if nothing is typed in the search bar, it does not clear the search results but instead it shows the data that has been found. How do I clear the search results if nothing is typed in the search bar. Here in the code what do I type if if(txt == '')?

Index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>LiveData</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Live Data Search</h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by ID" class="form-control" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var txt = $(this).val();
        if(txt != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetch.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {search:txt},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id12", "", "id127");
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datas WHERE ID LIKE '%" .$_POST["search"]."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '<h4 align = "center">Search Result</h4>';
 $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class = "table table bordered">
                   <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>
                </tr>
            ';
    }
    echo $output;

}
else
{
    echo "Data not found";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why not write the proper code for that? Is this related to MySQL after all? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: @NicoHaase I just have to make changes in fetch.php where i can clear the search results (output = ' ') if nothing is typed in the search box. I am not sure how to go ahead with this logic.

Comment: Sounds good. What's the expected result then? Where's the logic to check for your condition?

Comment: ```if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)``` is where I check if the input in the search bar matches for any value in mySQL table. If yes it will show the result, and if the entered value is not present in the table, it will display ```Data not found```. How do I clear the search results if nothing is entered in the search bar?

Comment: I have no idea why it's even necessary to return a string at all instead of returning a boolean...

Comment: I think I got it, in the code i have to add ```if(txt == ' ')``` and then clear the search bar. Right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are not checking what the fetch.php actually returns, you are just showing the returned values.

In case there is no result, I would simply return `false` instead of string and check this in the javascript, like:

```
if(returnValue === true) {
 ...
}else{
   $('#result').html("Nothing to show yet.");
}
```